# Broken git dependency from Atom Editor

Tags: git, debian, atom-editor, apt-get

I am trying to install Atom with the .deb file, and this package has git as dependency. I have installed git, but it was installed from source code, so the debian package manager doesn't see git. When i install atom, the git dependency is broken, and because of that any apt-get command that i tend to use doesn't work, it show a message about the git broken dependency.